# What is a more optimal way to change out an HTML element's.onClick element inside of a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm playing around with a webapp using React. My code currently creates a list of buttons that can change the color of a circle, depending on the randomly-generated button the user clicks on. To enhance my code, when the user clicks the button, I want all of the buttons colors to change, and therefore need to update all of the button's onClick functions, since they pass their color as an argument to the function that changes the circle's color. Below is the solution I currently have: it requires me to remove every button, and then completely reconstruct the button. Just using button.onclick = function() { newOnclickFunction} does not work, and I have not been able to find the answer on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated; I'm almost certain there's a better a way to do it than this.

```javascript
let reflipPalleteCompletely = () => {
      let everyButtonPossible = document.getElementsByClassName("colorChangeButton")
      for( var button of everyButtonPossible){
        button.style.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        let myParent = button.parentElement
        myParent.removeChild(button)
        let freshButton = document.createElement("button", {value: "Click", className: "colorChangeButton", })
        freshButton.innerHTML = 'Click'
        freshButton.className = 'colorChangeButton'
        freshButton.style.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        let newOnclickFunction = () => { changeToNewColor(button.style.backgroundColor); reflipPalleteCompletely() }
        freshButton.onclick = function() { newOnclickFunction() }
        myParent.appendChild(freshButton)
```

Comment: If you're using React, why are you manipulating the DOM *at all*? Just make your React code do that, that's literally what it's for. Give the parent a way to listen to clicks on the button collection, and make its handler give each button a new randomised `style` attribute. Then render() takes care of the rest.

Comment: Sounds like your react component should have a `button id/index => color` mapping which you use to look up the button's color when rendering them. Then you just update that mapping (which would trigger a rerender). That would be more in line with how React works. I recommend to read the React tutorial and docs: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html, https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html, especially https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Line breaks are your friend.

Comment: Fair enough, I did not specify that this is my first exploration into React and have been trying to use my beginner knowledge of JavaScript to make things work in it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: if each button is supposed to change color to reflect the color value it represents, and that set of colors is re-randomized every time a button is pressed, then you *can't* and *shouldn't* avoid re-render of the buttons.

However, Mike is right: you're not using React properly if you're writing your own element-creation scripts.

Your component might look like this:

```
const buttonCount = 10

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      currentColor: getRandomColor()
    }
  }

  setColor = (newColor, event) => {
    this.setState({
      currentColor: newColor
    })
  }

  render() {
    let {
      currentColor
    } = this.props

    let colorChoices = Array(buttonCount)
    .fill()
    .map(() => getRandomColor())

    return (
      <div className="Demo">

        <div className="the-shape" style={{ backgroundColor: currentColor }} />

        <ol className="color-choices">
          {
            colorChoices.map( color => (
              <button key={ color }
                style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
                onClick={ this.setColor.bind(this, color) }
              >
                { color }
              </button>
            ))
          }
        </ol>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This all depends on you having a `getRandomColor` function that can generate a color. And it doesn't address making sure that the choices don't include the current color (although you could easily do that by e.g. generating `2n` colors, filtering out the currentColor, then taking the first `n`, or somesuch).

If you really hate redrawing the buttons, you could save their refs and then have the `setColor` method iterate through them and modify their styles.

But the point of React is to avoid procedural mutation of the DOM in favor of declaring the desired DOM and letting the React engine figure out an efficient mutation strategy.

---

A direct answer to the question you asked: "what's a more optimal way to change out an HTML element's.onClick element?" might be: find a pattern that doesn't require you to change the function every time.

Instead of having this:

```
let newOnclickFunction = () => { changeToNewColor(button.style.backgroundColor); reflipPalleteCompletely() }
```

Try something like this instead:

```
function onClickButton(event) {
  let button = event.target
  let color = button.style.backgroundColor
  changeToNewColor(color)
}
```

This way, the desired color value isn't baked into the onClick function. Instead, the function examines the button whose click invoked it, and uses its background as the argument to `changeToNewColor`.

With some clever CSS, you could write the desired color to a `data-` prop on each button, and have the browser do the work of calculating `background-color` from that. Then you could use event delegation on some ancestor element that contains all the buttons, that listens for a click on any element with that `data-` prop and does the same work as above. This way, you don't even have a click function on each button.